# typedef type-alias = typedef

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

So, the [type-alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-alias) tag has been created.

So far as I can tell, it only applies to Swift.  There are only 63 questions.  The ones I saw all apply to Swift, and roughly two-thirds of these tags are from this year.

Ultimately, Swift's `type-alias` keyword is no different at all from the `typedef` keyword of its parent Objective-C, and of course the `typedef` keyword of languages such as C & C++.

I can see no reason for [type-alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-alias) to exist and instead think it should be a synonym of [typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typedef).

Comment: The typedef tag has a pretty specific wiki...

Comment: @TinyGiant Its wiki is probably *too* specific.  If the typedef tag is supposed to only be used for C/C++, what do I use to ask about typedef-ing in Objective-C? And why should Swift have a different tag, really?  It's exactly the same... just a slightly different keyword.

Comment: So I would start off by proposing a tag wiki edit that would allow those questions to be tagged [tag:typedef], then it is a pretty simple case of retagging. I do agree with the sentiment, but as it stands there isn't a clear path to the solution yet.

Comment: Of course, the C, C++ guys are pretty particular about their tags. You might want to take a quick poll of their respective chat rooms for general opinion.